# How to use min width property with weight in Android Compose

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I have two columns in a Row which I am diving on ratio of 1:3 using `Modifier.weight` field and this works fine. Let's call them ColumnA and ColumnB

I also have another requirement which states that if there is another layout element which is added dynamically in the Row at right end, the ColumnA should have a min fixed width. The ColumnB can take whatever space is available.

Default/Normal Scenario:

[image]

Desired Scenario:

[image]

I have explored using `defaultMinSize`, `minWidth` or `minWidthIn` but none of them are stopping ColumnA width to remain at this min fixed width value.

```
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(paddingValues)
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        //Divided in Ratio of 1:3
        ColumnA(Modifier.weight(1f)) //min width of 150 dp
        ColumnB(Modifier.weight(3f))
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean a min fixed value or max fixed value?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I do mean "minimum fixed width value defined in DPs" so that if there is a need that the whole layout has to shrink, the width of ColumnA doesn't go below that defined limit. 

Btw i have added two images in the main question for more clarification. 

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a way to know under which condition ColumnC is added you can add Modifiers that change using

`Modifier.then(if(!added) Modifier.weight(1f) else Modifier.width(100.dp))` to ColumnA and `Modifier.then(if(!added) Modifier.weight(3f) else Modifier.weight(1f)` to ColumnB.

If there is no way of knowing when ColumnC is added you should create a Layout, and define dimensions dinamically checking by assigning Modifer.layoutId() to ColumnC and checking if it exists in parent. You can refer about layout and Modifier.layoutId to this answer.

[Jetpack compose - Building a column with children separated by a divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574513/jetpack-compose-building-a-column-with-children-separated-by-a-divider/75575041#75575041)

Answer (score 0):

The `widthIn` property can be used by providing desired minimum width to the `min` argument for `ColumnA`. For `ColumnB`, `weight(1f)` can be used which will allow `ColumnB` to take the whole available space whether or not `ColumnC` is available. `ColumnC` can be used without any width restriction.

Here is an example.

```
@Composable
fun CellWithMinWidthProperty(
    text1: String,
    text2: String,
    text3: String? = null
) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(
            text = text1,
            modifier = Modifier.widthIn(min = 50.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = text2,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )
        text3?.let {
            Text(
                text = text3)
        }
    }
}
```